# Proving uniform convergence of $x^n-x^{2n}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, uniform-convergence

I need help checking if the series of function {$x^n-x^{2n}$} on two cases:

- when $0\le x\le 1$
- when $\frac{1}{3}\le x \le \frac{1}{2}$

I managed to prove that in the first case:

the limit function is $f(x)=0$ so $r(x)=x^n-x^{2n}$ I have a maximum point when $x=\frac{1}{2}^{\frac{1}{n}}$ so $lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}r(x)=\frac{1}{4}\ne 0$

my question is why Dini's theorem does not apply on this case.

for the second case:

I don't have a maximum point so how do I prove it uniformly converges?

any insight will be very helpful.

Comment: Most continuous functions on a closed finite interval have a maximum

Comment: @Henry *Most* functions? Are you aware of some exception?

Comment: $x^n-x^{2n}=\frac14-(x^n-\frac12)^2$

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos since $0$ is a number, I can confidently say there are a number of exceptions

Comment: @Henry Language tricks won't get you far around here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dini's theorem does not apply because the sequence is not monotone.

For the second case: $f'(x)=nx^{n-1}+2nx^{2n-1}=nx^{n-1}(1-2x^n)$, which is greater than $0$ in $\left[\frac13,\frac12\right]$. So, you *do* have a maximum: $\left(\frac12\right)^n-\left(\frac12\right)^{2n}=\left(\frac12\right)^n\left(1-\left(\frac12\right)^n\right)$. Since the limit of this sequence is $0$, your sequence converges uniformly to the null function.

Comment: thank you! this really helps